# Fix Bar Chart Width and Spacing between bars in StackedbarChart for any number of input

Tags: java, jfreechart

I  created a StackedBarChart with GroupedStackedBarRenderer for solving problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349933/how-to-create-a-stacked-bar-chart-with-multiple-rows-inside-one-row.

I can have any number of column key and row key, group.
Below, I attached some screenshots from my program.The problem is I could not get a standart view ( spaces betwen bars,too big bars if input is less, too thin bars which did not show  text written inside it).Before implementing this usecase, I would use setMaxbarWidth but now it does not work.

Here are the code which I use to arrange bars.

```
    CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(238, 238, 238));
    GroupedStackedBarRenderer renderer = new GroupedStackedBarRenderer();
    //Some insertion here
    KeyToGroupMap map = new KeyToGroupMap("A");
    renderer.setSeriesToGroupMap(map);
    renderer.setItemMargin(0.0);
    /** causes to show bar width half of available space. */
    renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(.5);
    renderer.setDrawBarOutline(true);
    renderer.setShadowVisible(false);
    plot.setRenderer(renderer);
    /** get number axis in plot.Number related axis .x axis in this graph. */
    NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();

    renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new CustomToolTipGenerator(getGraphData()));
    renderer.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
    /** do not show thick in number axis label */
    rangeAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
    rangeAxis.setTickMarksVisible(false);
    rangeAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
    CategoryAxis categoryAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    categoryAxis.setCategoryMargin(0.05);
    // categoryAxis.setLowerMargin(0.05);
    // categoryAxis.setUpperMargin(0.05);
    categoryAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
    categoryAxis.setTickMarksVisible(false);
    categoryAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
```

I know that there are some methods(setlowerMargin, setCategoryMargin, setUpperMargin) of CategoryDomain.I have made some tries over these methods.But no success. **I did not understand why space between bars are so wide**.Please help me

picture with 3 column key and 6 group

[image]
picture with 2 column key and 4 group

[image]

picture with one column key and 2 group

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what is wrong with code. I have a wrong KeyToGroup map.I  have not grouped any row key inside same groupKey.So I did not get desired view which I want.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to explore more of the negative range in `setItemMargin()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17342522/230513). You can adjust the slider to find the optimal value for your dataset. In the image below, the initial setting is `SLIDER_INITIAL_VALUE * INCREMENT`, which is `–4.2`.

[image]