# JFreeCharts Legend Text and Color Box Don't align

Tags: java, graph, alignment, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeCharts and creating a stacked bar graph. I have created a legend, but when I change the font for the legend to something like Calibri size 9, the text is not vertically aligned with the colored boxes.

The legend appears as follows:
[image]

The text is not vertically aligned with the boxes, It's like there is padding underneath or something. The following is my code for the customization of the chart

```
public JFreeChart createStackedChart(final CategoryDataset categorydataset, String Title) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
            Title, // chart title
            "", // domain axis label
            "", // range axis label
            categorydataset, // data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // the plot orientation
            true, // legend
            true, // tooltips
            false // urls
    );


    chart.setTitle(
            new org.jfree.chart.title.TextTitle(Title,
                    new java.awt.Font("Calibri", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 12)
            ));
    int columnCount = categorydataset.getColumnCount();
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    chart.getTitle().setPadding(10, 2, 10, 2);
    chart.setBorderVisible(true);
    chart.setBorderPaint(Color.lightGray);//akash change

    final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setDomainGridlineStroke(new BasicStroke(0.5f));
    plot.setRangeGridlineStroke(new BasicStroke(0.5f));
    plot.setOutlineVisible(true);
    plot.setOutlinePaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(0, 0, 0, 0));

    final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
    rangeAxis.setAutoRangeStickyZero(false);
    rangeAxis.setLowerMargin(0.0);

    rangeAxis.setTickLabelPaint(Color.black);
    rangeAxis.setTickMarkPaint(Color.lightGray);
    rangeAxis.setTickMarkStroke(new BasicStroke(0.3f));
    rangeAxis.setAxisLineStroke(new BasicStroke(0.3f));
    rangeAxis.setLowerBound(0.0f);

    rangeAxis.setAxisLinePaint(Color.lightGray);

    GroupedStackedBarRenderer renderer = new GroupedStackedBarRenderer();
    renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
    renderer.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());

    Paint p1 = new GradientPaint(
            0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0x22, 0x22, 0xFF), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0x88, 0x88, 0xFF)
    );
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, p1);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(4, p1);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(8, p1);

    Paint p2 = new GradientPaint(
            0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0x22, 0xFF, 0x22), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0x88, 0xFF, 0x88)
    );
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, p2);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(5, p2);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(9, p2);

    Paint p3 = new GradientPaint(
            0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0xFF, 0x22, 0x22), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0xFF, 0x88, 0x88)
    );
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, p3);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(6, p3);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(10, p3);

    Paint p4 = new GradientPaint(
            0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x22), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x88)
    );
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(3, p4);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(7, p4);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(11, p4);
    renderer.setGradientPaintTransformer(
            new StandardGradientPaintTransformer(GradientPaintTransformType.HORIZONTAL)
    );

    final CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    domainAxis.setTickLabelPaint(Color.black);
    domainAxis.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    Color transparent = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
    domainAxis.setAxisLinePaint(transparent);
    domainAxis.setTickMarkPaint(Color.darkGray);
    domainAxis.setTickMarkStroke(new BasicStroke(0.3f));
    domainAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelWidthRatio(4f);

    if (columnCount == 2) {
        domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(.6);
        domainAxis.setLowerMargin(0.015);
        domainAxis.setUpperMargin(0.015);
    } else if (columnCount == 3) {
        domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(.35);
        domainAxis.setLowerMargin(0.15);
        domainAxis.setUpperMargin(0.15);
    } else {
        domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(.55);
        domainAxis.setLowerMargin(0.015);
        domainAxis.setUpperMargin(0.015);
    }

    LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();//akash change
    legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.TOP);
    legend.setItemPaint(Color.black);
    chart.getLegend()
            .setFrame(BlockBorder.NONE);
    legend.setItemPaint(Color.GRAY);
    Font labelFont = new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 9);
    legend.setItemFont(labelFont);

    if (columnCount >= 5) {
        domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(
                CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 4.0));
        chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(0, 5, 0, 5));
    } else {
        domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(
                STANDARD);
    }
    plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);

    return chart;

}
```

The important lines include the areas in which I create the legend and change the font size. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17342522/230513), I see the expected result, illustrated below. Note that the relevant [`ChartFactory`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.955) "applies the default `JFree` chart theme," which defaults to `Tahoma`, also a sans-serif font.  I've exaggerated the size for convenience, and I've also used `deriveFont()` to change just the size.

```
LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();
…
Font labelFont = legend.getItemFont().deriveFont(20f);
legend.setItemFont(labelFont);
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.block.BlockBorder;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.GroupedStackedBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.title.LegendTitle;
import org.jfree.data.KeyToGroupMap;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.RectangleEdge;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17342522/230513
 */
public class DomainTranslateDemo extends ApplicationFrame {

    private static class DemoPanel extends JPanel implements ChangeListener {

        private static final int SLIDER_INITIAL_VALUE = -42;
        private static final double INCREMENT = 1 / 10.0;
        private final JSlider slider;
        private GroupedStackedBarRenderer renderer;

        public DemoPanel() {
            super(new BorderLayout());
            final CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
            final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
            final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart) {

                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(640, 360);
                }
            };
            add(chartPanel);

            JPanel dashboard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            dashboard.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 4, 4, 4));

            this.slider = new JSlider(-50, 10, SLIDER_INITIAL_VALUE);
            this.slider.addChangeListener(this);
            dashboard.add(this.slider);
            add(dashboard, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        private CategoryDataset createDataset() {
            DefaultCategoryDataset result = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
            result.addValue(1.5, "5YEUR", "5Y");
            result.addValue(-1.5, "5YUSD", "5Y");
            result.addValue(0.5, "5Yx5YEUR", "5Yx5Y");
            result.addValue(-0.5, "5Yx5YUSD", "5Yx5Y");
            result.addValue(1.5, "10Yx5YEUR", "10Yx5Y");
            result.addValue(-1.5, "10Yx5YUSD", "10Yx5Y");
            result.addValue(1.5, "15Yx5YEUR", "15Yx5Y");
            result.addValue(-1.5, "15Yx5YUSD", "15Yx5Y");
            result.addValue(1.5, "20Yx5YEUR", "20Yx5Y");
            result.addValue(-1.5, "20Yx5YUSD", "20Yx5Y");
            result.addValue(1.5, "20Yx5YEUR", "25Yx5Y");
            result.addValue(-1.5, "20Yx5YUSD", "25Yx5Y");
            return result;
        }

        private JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset) {

            final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
                "Max Bar Width", // chart title
                "Category", // domain axis label
                "Value", // range axis label
                dataset, // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // the plot orientation
                true, // legend
                true, // tooltips
                false // urls
            );

            LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();
            legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.TOP);
            legend.setFrame(BlockBorder.NONE);
            Font labelFont = legend.getItemFont().deriveFont(20f);
            legend.setItemFont(labelFont);

            renderer = new GroupedStackedBarRenderer();
            KeyToGroupMap map = new KeyToGroupMap("G1");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("5YEUR", "G1");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("5YUSD", "G1");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("5Yx5YEUR", "G2");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("5Yx5YUSD", "G2");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("10Yx5YEUR", "G3");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("10Yx5YUSD", "G3");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("15Yx5YEUR", "G4");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("15Yx5YUSD", "G4");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("20Yx5YEUR", "G5");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("20Yx5YUSD", "G5");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("25Yx5YEUR", "G6");
            map.mapKeyToGroup("25Yx5YUSD", "G6");
            renderer.setSeriesToGroupMap(map);
            renderer.setItemMargin(SLIDER_INITIAL_VALUE * INCREMENT);

            CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
            plot.setRenderer(renderer);
            return chart;
        }

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
            int value = slider.getValue();
            renderer.setItemMargin(value * INCREMENT);
        }
    }

    public DomainTranslateDemo(String title) {
        super(title);
        setContentPane(new DemoPanel());
    }

    public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
        return new DemoPanel();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DomainTranslateDemo demo = new DomainTranslateDemo("Translate Demo");
        demo.pack();
        demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I change the font to Calibri, will this still work?

Comment: It does for me; since you're using `ChartTheme` in several places, you may want to create your own `ChartTheme`.